# where put bussiness logic nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am developing a system in nodejs, but I don't know where to put the business logic, for example, it is an exam system when creating an exam. I need to calculate the value of each correct question in which part I should put this logic, it must be in the controller ?

Answer (score 2):

I usually separate the logic into different modules and they will have the below folder structure

-api

```
 -modules

   -user

      -user.model.js

      -user.service.js

      -user.controller.js
```

This folder structure will allow us to separate the service logic from controller. So that it will be easy to resuse the logic later. Controllers will handle only the difference status codes